# need help with several questions about jquery.jstree.js

Tags: jquery, jstree

How to get the currently selected node when click a button?

```
('#tree').jstree({...});  
('#button').click(function(){ :selected_node? })
```

How to refresh a node when click a button?

```
('#tree').jstree({...});  
('#button').click(function(){ :refresh? })
```

I would like to pop up a window to confirm a node is deleted. If 'cancel' is selected, the node should not be deleted. Whether can I do that and how?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Go to the jstree google group where many questions have been aswered by the creators and community.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this will depend a little on which jstree plugin you are using to generate the tree.  I'm using the HTML plugin and achieve the confirmation requirement as follows.

For each row there is a set of icons to perform various tasks on the tree each has a class of `icon` and a further class to identify the action, for example:

```
<li class="row" id="26">
    <a href="/admin/pages/add-edit/?pageId=26" class="treeLink">Home Page</a>
    <div class="iconRow">
    <a class="icon icon-tick" title="Active">Active</a>
    <a href="/admin/pages/move/?pageId=26&direction=up" class="icon icon-arrow-up" title="Move Up">Move Up</a>
    <a href="/admin/pages/move/?pageId=26&direction=down" class="icon icon-arrow-down" title="Move Down">Move Down</a>
    <a href="/admin/pages/add-edit/?pageId=26" class="icon icon-page-edit" title="Edit">Edit</a>
    <a href="/admin/pages/delete/?pageId=26" class="icon icon-page-delete" title="Delete">Delete</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

So from here my jQuery code looks something like:

$('a.icon').live('click' ,function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('icon-arrow-up') || $(this).hasClass('icon-arrow-down')) {
        //Do something here....
    }

```
if ($(this).hasClass('icon-page-delete')) {
    //Add confirmation box code here
}
```

return false;
});

This is quite a simplistic look at it but hopefully will get you started on the way.